# Prevent Code Behind from loading Facebook Pixel Code again if it is already loaded on the Front End?

Tags: dotnetnuke, facebook-pixel

My module needs to submit a Complete Registration Facebook Pixel Event when a registration has been completed.

On the Facebook Pixel Helper tool, it says that the Pixel Code loaded twice.
Sometimes it doesn't.

I have got the Pixel tracking code on all the Skin files in DNN.

Sometimes a post-back happens and I need to load it again in the Code-Behind when the "Registration Successful" message loads along with the Facebook Tracking Event.

What can I add to the IF statement below to check if the Facebook Pixel code hasn't already loaded on the Front End?

This is my code:

```
 RegUserFacebookPixelID = TryGetPortalSetting("FacebookPixelID");

if (RegUserFacebookPixelID != null)
{
    string FacebookPixelResult = string.Empty;

    using (var FBPxl = new StringWriter())
    using (var FBCodescript = new HtmlTextWriter(FBPxl))
    {
        FBCodescript.AddAttribute(Attr.Type, "text/javascript");
        FBCodescript.RenderBeginTag(Tag.Script);
        //load ecommerce plugin
        FBCodescript.WriteLine("!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if (f.fbq) return; n = f.fbq = function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};");
        FBCodescript.WriteLine("if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n; n.push = n; n.loaded = !0; n.version = '2.0';");
        FBCodescript.WriteLine("n.queue =[]; t = b.createElement(e); t.async = !0;");
        FBCodescript.WriteLine("t.src = v; s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];");
        FBCodescript.WriteLine("s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)}");
        FBCodescript.WriteLine("(window, document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');");
        FBCodescript.RenderEndTag();
        FBCodescript.WriteLine($"<noscript><img height='1' width='1' style='display:none'  src='https://www.facebook.com/tr?id={RegUserFacebookPixelID}&ev=PageView&noscript=1'/></noscript>");
        FacebookPixelResult = FBCodescript.InnerWriter.ToString();
    }

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myFacebookPixelInitialization", FacebookPixelResult, false);
}
```

Comment: Can't you add a HiddenField (or normal input=hidden) on the page and fill that with a y/n pixel loaded. Then on PostBack read that `Value` or `Request.Form` and show the pixel based on that?

Comment: Great suggestion. It turned out the Facebook code in the backend was missing  fbq('init', '{RegDealerFacebookPixelID}');   fbq('track', 'PageView');"